# Hotkeys for navigating and using the solution explorer in vscode?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

I'm on ubuntu so when I press `ctrl`+`shift`+`E` opening and entering the solution explorer I have a few questions:

1) Can I through hotkeys close files without leaving the solution explorer (or at all?). I.e. simulate the effect of clicking on the `x`-symbol next to the file-names?

2) When I enter the solution explorer I can "go through" the open editors by using the up/down arrows. Below these I can see the structure of my current folder. Is there any way of "jumping down" and go through the files/folders of my current folder through up/down arrows? Or manipulating the folder (like triggering new file, new folder, refresh, collapse all) from the keyboard?

3) Can I delete files at all from vscode? In the shortcuts there is a  `deleteFile` command supposedly triggered by `shift`+`delete` but I haven't figured out where and how to trigger it?

I suppose I could do `ctrl`+`K` `P` and then run `rm` `filepath` in the terminal. I suppose that's reasonably smooth way of doing it but would still like to know more about these functionalities in vscode

Answer (score 0):

I've found commands (that I've bound hotkeys for) for most of my questions:

2 and 3)

`workbench.files.action.focusFilesExplorer` set the focus to the files in the explorer

`workbench.files.action.focusOpenEditorsView` set the focus to the editors in the explorer

There should be coupled with when-clauses:
`explorerViewletFocus` and `filesExplorerFocus` respectively

In the keybindings, just search `explorer` and you'll find a bunch of commands to use on files in the filesexplorer. (delete file being one of them)

I still don't have the answer for 1) though and will hopefully wait for someone to give that information. When hoovering over the `x`-symbol it says "Close editor (ctrl+w)" though this will change focus from the explorer, so you can't easily just close a bunch of open editors smoothly through this method.

EDIT: Just realized that it's just called "explorer" it's a directory/editor explorer. Not a solution explorer.